# L'expression « pas grand-chose »

Tags: genre

Pourquoi dit-on

> Ce n'est pas grand-chose.

au lieu de

> Ce n'est pas grande chose.

?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Cela vient de l'ancien français ou "grande" s'écrivait "grand" (on prononçait les lettres en fin de mot jusqu'au XVIIe siècle) et son masculin s'écrivait "grant".

Depuis, en français moderne, on rajoute un "e" au féminin en adéquation aux règles de français moderne.

D'autres expressions s'écrivent encore avec des `formes figées*`, comme "grand-mère", "grand-soif", "grand-faim", "grand-route" (etc...) par exemple.

*Les critères qui définissent qu'une expression est figée ont été définis par Maurice Gross:

> 1 -La polylexicalité.
>
> Une expression figée correspond à une séquence de
>   plusieurs mots, dont chacun doit avoir par ailleurs une existence
>   autonome. Soit l'expression ci-dessous :  Les murs ont des oreilles .
>   Les termes « murs » et « oreilles » ont bien une existence autonome,
>   attestée par leur présence dans les dictionnaires.
>
> 2) L'opacité
>
> sémantique Dans une expression traditionnelle, le sens de la séquence
>   est le produit de celui de ses éléments composants : c'est le concept
>   de compositionnalité. Ainsi le sens d'une phrase est facteur de celui
>   de ses arguments. Prenons un exemple de phrase dont le sens est
>   compositionnel : L'enfant lit un livre. La phrase entière a un sens
>   grâce à la combinaison des sens dits classiques de « enfant » « lire »
>   et « livre ». Une expression figée ne relève pas de ce genre de
>   lecture. Elle se heurte à une opacité sémantique. Pour reprendre notre
>   exemple, « les murs ont des oreilles » signifie « on peut nous
>   entendre ». Selon la démarche compositionnelle, le sens devrait être
>   le produit du sens de « murs », « avoir » et « oreilles ». Ce n'est
>   pas le cas car le sens d'une expression figée ne peut se déduire de
>   celui de ses composants.
>
> 3) Le blocage des propriétés
>
> transformationnelles. Une expression figée ne peut être transformée
>   syntaxiquement. On ne peut pas dire :
>   *  Ce sont les oreilles qu'a eut le mur . (extraction)
>   *  Le mur les a . (prominalisation)
>   *  Les oreilles que le mur a eu . (relativation) L'opacité sémantique et les restrictions syntaxiques sont étroitement liées. Le phénomène
>   du figement « transcende ce qu'on appelle généralement les différents
>   niveaux de l'analyse linguistique et une description qui ne serait que
>   syntaxique ou sémantique ne retiendrait qu'une partie des faits ».
>
> 4) La non-actualisation des éléments.
>
> Les éléments d'une expression
>   figée ne sont pas susceptibles d'être actualisés. Par exemple, on ne
>   peut pas dire : Les murs ont des (*une, *ces) oreilles.
>
> 5) Le blocage
>
> des paradigmes synonymiques. Dans une expression figée, il est
>   impossible de remplacer un élément par un de ses synonymes.
>   *  Les cloisons ont des oreilles.
>   *  Les murs possèdent des oreilles.
>
> 6) L'impossibilité d'insertion.
>
> Il est impossible d'insérer des
>   éléments supplémentaires dans une
>   expression figée. A la différence des suites libres, où on peut
>   insérer des éléments tels qu'un adjectif, une relative, une incise ou
>   un adverbe d'intensité, à des endroits précis. Il est impossible de
>   dire :
>   *  Les murs ont des oreilles sales.
>   *  Les murs, qui ont été construits l'année dernière, ont des oreilles.

Comment: *Quelque chose* est aussi masculin. Est-ce que la raison ne serait pas plutôt que les emplois indéfinis de *chose* sont tous masculins ?

Comment: C'est l'expression "Quelque chose" qui est, il me semble, un pronom indéfini et donc n'a ni valeur de masculin ni de féminin.

"Chose" perd d'ailleurs sa valeur de nom. "Quelque chose" "grand-chose" etc... sont invariables.

Comment: Dans le même registre que « grand-route », on peut aussi citer « grand-rue ». On peut peut-être aussi noter les pluriels particuliers (« des grand**s** père**s** » mais « des grand-mère**s** »).

Comment: Pourriez-vous svp préciser dans la réponse de quel ouvrage de M. Gross il s'agit ou une source qui incorpore le texte que vous présentez ? Merci !

Comment: A noter que si grand-mère ou grand-route sont assez communs, grand-faim ou grand-soif sont par contre assez vieillots... si j'entends quelqu'un dire "J'ai grand-faim", je pense d'office au film "Les visiteurs"...

Comment: L'une des attactions touristique de Rouen est "le grand horloge" qui date de la fin du XIVème siécle.

Answer (score 3):

Your question could be asked about similar cases such as why we do say ***grand-mère*** but not ***grande-mère***.

There is one simple reason for that: in ancient French language, the adjective grand is gender neutral. Later on, it was decided to make it as other adjectives without modifying the old expressions such as *grand-mère*, *grand chose* and so on.

Answer (score 3):

Un complément sur le *grand-chose* dans *pas grand-chose* :

> Ô fantôme muet, ô notre ombre, ô notre hôte,
>  Spectre toujours
>   masqué qui nous suis côte à côte,
>  Et qu’on nomme demain !
>   *Oh ! demain, c’est la grande chose !*
>  De quoi demain sera-t-il fait ?
>  L’homme aujourd’hui sème la cause,
>  Demain Dieu fait
>   mûrir l’effet.
>
> [ Victor Hugo, [*Napoléon II*](https://fr.wikisource.org/wiki/Napol%C3%A9on_II) - ds. *Les Chants du crépuscule*,
>   extrait ]

C'est un exemple qui confirme le *figement* dont on traite en [réponse](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/16301) en ce sens qu'il illustre ce qui se produit quand il tombe : le genre du mot *chose* (f.) s'impose à nouveau et *grand* s'accorde en genre (*grande*; et le trait d'union n'est plus incidemment).<sup>1</sup> En poussant au bout le raisonnement, on notera, tel qu'on l'identifie en [commentaire](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/16300/lexpression-pas-grand-chose#comment30435_16301), qu'il y a des conséquences :

> Dans toutes ces locutions [*autre chose, grand-chose, peu de chose,
>   quelque chose*], qui sont des pronoms nominaux indéfinis, *chose* perd
>   son statut de nom et, du même coup, son genre; ces locutions sont donc
>   neutres et les mots qui s’y rapportent doivent être au masculin et au
>   singulier.
>  [...]
>   *Nos expériences n’ont pas donné grand-chose de **bon**.*
>
> [ *Banque de dépannage linguistique*, BDL, [*chose*](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?T1=grand%20chose&T3.x=0&T3.y=0) ]

---

Au *TLFi* on identifie *grand-[chose](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/chose/1)* comme un « *mot-outil pour l'expression de l'inanimé; élément nominal formant avec l'élément adjoint un syntagme binaire qui a valeur de pronom ou d'adverbe indéfini neutre.* ». [*Larousse*](http://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/grand-chose/37823/difficulte) parle d'*adverbe*. Par ailleurs, la locution *pas grand-chose*, avec la négation, contrairement à *grand-chose* (valeurs positives plus fréquentes à l'époque [classique](http://atilf.atilf.fr/scripts/dmfX.exe?IDF=dmfXdXrmXcbj;ISIS=isis_dmf2012.txt;MENU=menu_dmf;OUVRIR_MENU=2;OO1=-1;s=s071a19b8;LANGUE=FR;FERMER;AFFICHAGE=2;MENU=menu_dmf;;XMODE=STELLa;FERMER;;)), a, elle, vocation à être sujet, comme *peu de chose*. On note aussi au passage que c'est en 1932 que l'*Académie* remplace la forme originale *grand'chose* par la forme *grand-chose* avec le trait d'union.<sup>2</sup> À ce sujet le *LBU* a une opinion négative de la position de l'*Académie* de l'an 2000 au sujet du trait d'union dans de tels mots et sur l'analyse de ce qu'on retrouvait en ancien françcais ; on réfère à « *grand* » II, 4 dans *Ac.* 9 :

> ☆4. **Remarque**. Devant un nom féminin commençant par une consonne, *Grand*
>   restait invariable en ancien français. Cet usage s'est conservé dans
>   certaines locutions et certains mots composés qu'on a écrits avec une
>   apostrophe, comme *grand'chose*, *grand'faim*, *grand'messe*, *grand'mère*,
>   *grand'pitié*, *grand'route*, etc. Aujourd'hui, on emploie généralement le
>   trait d'union pour unir les deux termes, comme dans *grand-chose*,
>   *grand-mère*, à *grand-peine*, *grand-messe*. Dans certaines locutions,
>   l'emploi du trait d'union n'est pas systématique. On pourra écrire
>   *grand-faim* ou *grand faim*, *grand-peur* ou *grand peur*, *grand-route* ou
>   *grand route*, *grand-rue* ou *grand rue*, etc., sans que la langue
>   littéraire ou archaïsante s'interdise dans ces cas l'emploi de
>   l'apostrophe. • **Dans ces noms féminins composés,** *Grand*, **ne s'accordant
>   pas en genre, ne s'accorde pas non plus en nombre.**
>
> [ *Dictionnaire de l'Académie française*, [*grand*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/academie9/grand) II, 4, en gras dans l'entrée ]

C'est que le *LBU* identifie des cas où un mot ne débutait pas par une consonne et où *grand* s'accordait en nombre à défaut de s'accorder en genre (*mult gran**z** amistez* (amitiés), Roland ; *de gran**s** ailes dorées*, Ronsard).<sup>3</sup>

---

Enfin, on a *un/une/ces pas grand-chose* toujours invariable en substantif, dit familièrement et/ou péjorativement pour *la/les personne(s) de peu de valeur*.

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> Exemple et explication tirés du *LBU* (*Le bon usage*, Grevisse et Goosse, ed. Duculot) au §543.</sub> 
<sub><sup>2</sup> Explications tirées du *LBU* au §764 (b, note H1), où l'on présente aussi des situations où les expressions dont on traite ne sont pas figées. On dit que l'origine de l'apostrophe dans *grand'mère* était une croyance erronée «  *qu'un e final était disparu comme dans l’élision*. » (§543 note H2)</sub> 
<sub><sup>3</sup> Quant aux cas spécifiques des pluriels de noms composés comme *grand(s)-mères*, auxquelles on a fait [allusion](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/16300/lexpression-pas-grand-chose#comment30437_16301), les avis sont partagés, [Ac.9](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/academie9/grand-m%C3%A8re) optant pour ne pas faire l'accord du premier élément alors qu'on l'avait soit disant encouragé dans leur *Grammaire*. *TLFi* de même, et on en retrace [historique](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/grand) au bas de l'entrée. [*Larousse*](http://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/grand-m%C3%A8re/37854?q=grand-m%C3%A8re#37797) suggère l'un ou l'autre, et le *LBU* trouve justifiée l'invariabilité en nombre seulement en contexte de l'apostrophe, qu'on a abolie, et ne considère pas que l'invariabilité en genre doit emporter celle en nombre dans ce contexte. (Voir *LBU* au §529, en particulier la note H1).</sub>

Answer (score 1):

Il faut remonter au latin pour expliquer les nombreuses expressions du type *grand-mère*, *grand route*, *grand faim*, *grand peine*, etc.  L'adjectif latin *grandis* se classe dans la troisième des cinq déclinaisons du latin et, partant, ne présente qu'une seule forme pour le masculin et le féminin.  *Grand-mère* etc. est un reflet du système des déclinaisons de l'adjectif en latin.

Comme l'explique Martin Maiden dans *The Cambridge History of the Romance Languages (Vol. I)* :

- A shadow of the old declension class system [of Latin] survives, in that adjectives [such as *uiridis*] which originally belonged to the third declension do not inflectionally distinguish gender: e.g., Spanish *techo verde* ‘green roof’, *casa verde* ‘green house’; Italian *tetto verde*, *casa verde*; Romanian *acoperiș verde*, *casă verde*.  In contrast, feminine adjectives in first declension -a have a masculine counterpart in -o, and vice versa (Spanish *techo blanco* ‘white roof’, *casa blanca* ‘white house’; Italian *tetto bianco*, *casa bianca*; Romanian *acoperiș alb*, *casă albă*).  This vestigial declensional difference has been erased in many varieties where word-final -e and -o have been deleted (French, Occitan, Catalan, Raeto-Romance) by widespread extension of the feminine inflection to original third declension adjectives: Catalan *la casa verda*, French *le toit vert* but l*a maison verte*.  **Some traces of earlier gender-invariant third declension adjectives survive in modern French expressions containing feminine nouns, such as *grand-mère* ‘grandmother’, *avoir grand faim* ‘to be very hungry’ (but *la grande maison* ‘the big house’).**