# Why "grand-mère", but not "grandE-mère" ?

Tags: grammaire

I have two questions about the word "grand-mère":

1. Why does one write "grand-mère" but not "grand**e**-mère"? La mère is feminine, so why doesn't one use the adjective "grande", instead of "grand"?
2. Is "grand/grande" also means "great" (respectful personality), beside its main meaning, "tall"?

Comment: Mr. @jlliagre, I'm a beginner and I can't speak French yet. So, I cannot read that post because all questions and answers are french there.

Comment: There is a reply in English that summarizes well the reason why there is no *E* in grand-mère : https://french.stackexchange.com/a/16303/1109