# Quels adjectifs peut-on apocoper en français ?

Tags: adjectifs

Au fil de mes lectures j'ai plusieurs fois croisés des locutions comme "la grand vie" ou "la grand ville".

Cela me fait penser à l'espagnol où l'on a le même phénomène pour certains adjectives (bueno, santo, etc) mais au masculin.

Quels sont les autres adjectifs en français qui peuvent s'utiliser au masculin devant un nom féminin ?

Comment: À propos du pourquoi du phénomène (grand devant un nom féminin) voir [cette question](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/16300/358) et ses réponses. Le phénomène étant spécifiquement lié à l'étymologie et l'histoire du mot il est possible qu'il n'y ait pas d'autres cas semblables.

Comment: On dit « nu-tête » (et demi-heure et mi-temps) mais la raison est différente de ce qui se passe dans "grand rue", etc.

Answer (score 1):

Il ne s'agit pas d'une apocope comme on en trouve en espagnol. Aucune n'existe en français à ma connaissance.

Comment: Je viens d'apprendre quelque chose auourd'hui !
En recherchant sur Wikipedia (https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apocope), j'ai pu voir des adjectifs : catho, claustro, dégueu, dispo...